# ¿Como exportar una respuesta JSON compleja a XLS, con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, nodejs, excel

¡Hola todos!

¿Saben de alguna herramienta que pueda generar un XLS desde una respuesta JSON?

Pretendo hacer una consulta, sin mostrarla en una tabla, y en base a ello elaborar el XLS lo más personalizable que se pueda (similar a PHPEXCEL, donde se tiene control sobre las celdas), ya que la respuesta es algo compleja y entre más control tenga sobre el documento será mejor.

No sé si exista (se me haría raro que no), pero ya busque y no encuentro nada, todos hablan de cosas demasiado simples. Agradecería mucho cualquier información.

***Estoy usando Angular JS y Node JS***

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar la estructura de tu json por favor?

Comment: En realidad lo que necesitas es transformar una matriz o array 2d a un xls. Lo digo porque no hay librerías que puedan decidir con qué criterio llevar un objeto a una matriz.

Comment: revisad: https://github.com/functionscope/Node-Excel-Export - https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls - https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-excel si logras hacerlo funcionar con estos enlaces, publica la respuesta y colabora con el crecimiento de la comunidad de SOes! :D

Comment: En la mayoría de los sitios de la red [se] no se permiten las preguntas del listo ¿alguna herramienta...? porque esta se consideran del tipo basadas en opiniones. Por favor considera replantear tu pregunta a algo más específico, para más detalles consulta [ask] y [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final solucione mi problema al 90%.
Realice la exportación desde Node JS, con ayuda de esta herramienta: [Node-excel-export](http://github.com/functionscope/Node-Excel-Export), es muy buena, con un poco de ingenio armas una estructura algo decente, ademas te permite la creacion de distintas hojas.

Pero digo al 90%, porque no consegui aplicar estilos mediante XML. En fin dejo la recomendación por si le sirve a alguien más.